# Run Linux script at startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

Although I have created a file in /etc/rc0 directory to get it run at startup I does not execute.
On the contrary when same file is created at /etc/rc6 directory, it gets executed upon shuting down.

K99startup.sh -> ../init.d/startup.sh*

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the script from `/etc/rc.local` which is the correct place for custom scripts to run at startup.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/local/bin/your-script

exit 0
```

Comment: What is the exact difference way os usage of this file from using os run-level directory files?

Comment: I have created same file at both /etc/rc2.d /etc/rc3/d folder but it does not either. I am testing this functionality via reboot command.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Linux runlevel 6 is reboot/shutdown. 
What you're looking for is runlevel 3 or/and 5.

The standard tools for managing startup scripts are [chkconfig](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_chkconfig.htm) or [update.rc](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Update-rc.d).
But if you want to be "on the edge" you can use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) - which was presented in Ubuntu some time ago.

Upstart jobs are located under `/etc/init`- you just have to copy an existing job and use it as example/template to write your own job for your script. 
Most of the people recommend looking at `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

runlevel 6 is used during reboot. http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/212

try using /etc/rc2.d and name it S99startup.sh the S prefix is for Start and the K prefix is for Kill.